# W2 details for foreign earned income tax exemption

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, form-w-2, foreign-income

I'm planning on being out of the US for a 12-month period, and plan to take the foreign earned income exemption.

The problem is that my employer uses a payroll service which can only issue a W2 listing a US address (my mailing address, but I won't be there). Is that likely to be an issue?

To get the exemption, I'll also have to fill out [form 2555](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-2555) in which I state that I've been out of the country. So I'm not sure if a W2 inconsistent with that will raise eyebrows. BTW I'm not staying in a single other country, but moving a lot during the one year abroad, so have no single address for the W2.

In other words, will putting my US mailing address on the W2 raise eyebrows?

Comment: I doubt it; W2's (and 1099's etc) are mailed after the end of the year they apply to -- if at all; nowadays they can be delivered electronically if you agree (which I expect you would). But I don't have personal experience, or a an authoritative reference. Bon voyages!